# space between div and page sides

Tags: html, css

i have few divs with `width :100%`. when I ran the code I get space between the divs and the sides of the page (right and left).

that's my html code:

```
<div id="main_pics" class="container">
<!-- photos here -->

</div>

<div id="other1" class="container">

</div>

<div id="other2" class="container">
</div>
```

that's my css code:

```
#main_pics{
margin-top: 57px;
/*background-color: rgb(224,224,224);*/
/*border: 1px solid black;*/
}

.container{
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color: white;
}

#other1{
background-color: rgb(224,224,224);
width: 100%;
}

#other2{
width: 100%;
background-color:fuchsia;
}
```

I set the `#main_pics` to  `margin-top: 57px`, because above it there is a nav bar.

anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: body has margin by default I believe, you'd need to remove it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the default `body` element `margin`, you can remove with CSS :

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ro1o08s3/)